# How can I draw features on GeoTIFF in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a set of data (coords + value) and want to turn it into a heatmap in GeoTIFF. Should I calculate pixels and set them as array, or there are shortcuts?

This is what I do now:

```
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    dst_ds = driver.Create('%s-%s.tif' % (name, zoom), height, width, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    raster = numpy.zeros((width, height))

    cur.execute('select * from image')
    for i, row in enumerate(cur):
        raster[row[0], row[1]] = row[2]
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
 band = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
 for row in cursor:
     band.drawCircle((row[0], row[1]), 20, row[2])
```

The important part is saving the depth of data.

Comment: I don't know of any support for direct drawing for raster. GRASS has a simple rasteredit gui and I once intended to write one for QGIS but don't have the time right now. What you could do instead is to draw a vector (for instance a 20m buffer) and rasterize it in python.

Comment: It looks interesting, I actually could just drop everything in a big SVG, but I don't know how to merge many circles or thick lines into one image (they have different values) and how to manage this transparency balancing, because the result has only 256 grades. The advantage of TIFF is that I can drop direct values there.